# want to implement ajax file upload in my user profile form for picture upload

Tags: jquery, ajax, file-upload

imple ajax upload , want to know how to implement it in my code ... I have searched lot of uploader not know how to implement it in my code.

$('#message_form').html('Profile Information Edit'+
        ''+
        ''+
        'First Name :'+
        'Last Name :'+
        'E- Mail :'+
        'Photo :'+
        ''+
        ''+
        'Gibs Owned:'+
        ''
    );

```
MessageWindow.show();
$(".cancel").click(function() {

    MessageWindow.hide();
});
$(".submit").click(function() {
    ajaxFileUpload();
    var dataString = $("#myform").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: YAPI.baseUrl+"updateuser.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(data){
            response = eval('('+data+')');
            alert(response.message);
            YAPI.execute({command:'getuser',userid:App.currentUser.getData('userid')},
                function(response,data){
                    //App.currentUser.setData();
                }
            );

            MessageWindow.hide();
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: You are showing a lot of badly-structured code that is very hard to understand. I doubt anybody will be able (and willing) to fix or change this code for you, especially seeing that you're not giving any real information.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666921/easiest-way-to-make-a-form-submit-without-refresh/3666981#3666981 Take a look at pekka's comment on that post.

Comment: i have html in the code that i am not able to show here in code block

Comment: $('#message_form').html('Profile Information Edit'+
  '<form id="myform" enctype="multipart/form-data">'+
  '<input type="hidden" id="userid" name="userid" value='+App.currentUser.getData('userid')+'>'+
  '<table><tr><td>First Name :</td><td><input type="text" name="firstname" value="'+user.getData('firstname')+'"></td></tr>'+
  '<tr><td>Last Name :</td><td><input type="text" name="lastname" value="'+user.getData('lastname')+'"></td></tr>'+
  '<tr><td>E- Mail :</td><td><input type="text" name="email" value="'+user.getData('email')+'">'+

Comment: '<tr><td>Photo :</td><td><input type="file" id="photo" name="photo" value="'+user.getData('email')+'">'+
  '<tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" class="submit " value="Submit" />'+
  '<input type="button" class="cancel " value="Cancel" />'+
  '<tr><td colspan="2">Gibs Owned:</tr><tr><td colspan="2"><div id="divTxt"></div>'+
  '</form>'
 );

Comment: @Rahul did you read @Robert's comment? Also, adding even more code is not going to improve your question...

Comment: @Rahul That is definitely not the best way to insert in HTML dynamically. Either have that HTML fragment hidden on your page, then unhide it when needed, or build your way up the form with separate DOM insertions. Putting a giant chunk of HTML into your Javascript is just wrong.

Comment: @all tell me the solution na how can i do this ....

Answer (score 0):

If possible, try to use jQuery plugins like Uploadify. Also, check this for more info:
[Asynchronous file upload (AJAX file upload) using jsp and javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276916/asynchronous-file-upload-ajax-file-upload-using-jsp-and-javascript)